# Coredata object got removed from the relationship automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am facing an issue with coredata relationship. Here is my problem scenario step wise

1. I have two tables in core data. "ContactTable" and "GroupTable".
2. "GroupTable" has one-to-many relationship with "ContactTable" and "ContactTable" has one-to-one relationship with "GroupTable". That means the tables have inverse relationship.
3. "ContactTable" has some records e.g. "Name1", "Name2", "Name3" etc.
4. Now suppose I create a group e.g. "Group1" in "GroupTable" and save all above 3 contact in the one-to-many relationship of "GroupTable" to "ContactTable".
5. Now I create a second group e.g. "Group2" in "GroupTable" and save all above 3 contact in the one-to-many relationship of "GroupTable" to "ContactTable".

Problem : When I print the members of "Group2" from relationship of  "GroupTable" all 3 records are printed, but When I print the members of "Group1" from relationship of "GroupTable", there are no records. Similarly if I keep on creating new groups with the same 3 contacts the records printed only in the last group.

Can anyone help me out in this or suggest any approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of defining the relationship from `ContactTable` to `GroupTable` as "to-one": each `Contact` can be related to only one `Group`.  Hence when you save the 3 `Contact`s to "Group2", CoreData automatically removes them from "Group1".

If you want instances of `Contact` to belong to both "Group1" and "Group2", then you must define the relationship from `ContactTable` to `GroupTable` as "to-many".

Comment: Thanks, this is an accepted answer for me and solved my problem that I was facing from many days